# How to run automatically my application after keypad unlock

Tags: android

I need a code to run my application automatically after keypad unlock. 
if any one know how to implement please answer me..!

Comment: Do you mean you want to launch app when soft keyboard pops out? I see no reason to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the action `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` which is broadcasted when the user is present after device wakes up (e.g when the keyguard is gone). You'll need to declare a broadcast receiver that listens to this action and launch your app from there.

- [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)
- [Broadcast receiver tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

*Note that you'd want to change the action from the tutorial to the one that I just mentioned.*